# how to convert data.frame to transactions for arules

Tags: r, transactions, attributes, arules

I read data from a csv file, the data has 3 columns, one is transaction id, the other two are product and product catagory. I need to convert this into transactions in order to use the `apriori` function in **arules**. It shows an error when I convert to transactions:

```
dat <- read.csv("spss.csv",head=TRUE,sep="," , as.is = T)
dat[,2] <- factor(dat[,2])
dat[,3] <- factor(dat[,3])
spssdat <- dat[,c(1,2,3)]
str(spssdat)

'data.frame':   108919 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Transaction_id: int  3000312 3000312 3001972 3003361 3003361 3003361 3003361 3003361 3003361 3004637 ...
 $ product_catalog : Factor w/ 9 levels "AIM","BA","IM",..: 1 1 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 ...
 $ product      : Factor w/ 332 levels "ACM","ACTG/AIM",..: 7 7 159 61 61 61 61 61 61 7 ...

trans4 <- as(spssdat, "transactions")

Error in as(spssdat, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “data.frame” to “transactions”
```

If the data only have two columns, it can work by:

```
trans4 <- as(split(spssdat[,2], spssdat[,1]), "transactions")
```

But I don't know how to convert when I have 3 columns. Usually there are the additional columns likes category attributes, customer attributes. so the column usually large than 2 columns. need to find rules between multiple columns.

Answer (score 23):

I have found some information that worked for me on [this website](http://statistical-research.com/data-frames-and-transactions/). Let me copy relevant paragraph:

> The dataframe can be in either a normalized (**single**) form or a flat file (**basket**) form.
>   When the file is in **basket** form it means that **each record represents a transaction** where the items in the basket are represented by columns.
>   When the dataset is in **single** form it means that **each record represents one single item and each item contains a transaction id**.

To load transactions from file, use `read.transactions`. In both your and my case file is in the **single** form.
I've used following code to load .csv file as `transactions`:

```
trans = read.transactions("some_data.csv", format = "single", sep = ",", cols = c("transactionID", "productID"))
```

To fully understand above command, take a look at `read.transactions` manual, available after typing `?read.transactions` in R console.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how this function is supposed to work. I've got a CSV file with column headers. The ID column is a set of dates. All the other column are binary 1s and 0s. Is this function designed to parse that kind of data? When I try running the code you provided, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's been quite some time since I worked in R, but I think the code should work, as long as you pass relevant column headers (`cols`) and separator (`sep`) to the function. Hard to say without an example of your data format.

Comment: Thks so much... I almost invent the Hot towel before reading your  response.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I was attempting to do the same thing and after I factored all my columns in the data.frame I was working with, I still could not coerce it into an itemMatrix of transactions.  Then I realized I never re-loaded the "arules" package for the session I was working in.  Very stupid mistake, but just wanted to mention it in case anyone else runs into the same problem, try the simple stuff first:

```
library("arules")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert "Transaction_id" into a factor variable.