# How to create itemsets in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a table with two columns `Category`,`Number` and a lot of rows in a `CSV` file. Each value like `1` in `Category` has a relation with some values like `1`,`2`,...,`k` in `Number`. In other words, my table is:

```
Category     Number
1            1
1            2
.
.
.
1            100
2            101
2            102
.
.
.
2            200
.
.
.
```

I want to create `itemsets` according to the table in `CSV` file using `R`, something like this:

```
1 = (1, 2, ..., 100)
2 = (101, 102, ..., 200)
.
.
.
```

I googled, but I didn't find any solutions. How can I do this?

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313450/how-to-convert-data-frame-to-transactions-for-arules

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand but maybe one of the two following is what you want.

```
dat <- data.frame(Category = rep(1:2, each = 100), Number = 1:200)

aggregate(Number ~ Category, dat, list)
aggregate(Number ~ Category, dat, function(x) paste0('(', paste(x, collapse = ", "), ')'))
```

The first `aggregate` returns a dataframe where the second column, `Number` are lists with the elements you call `itemsets`.
The second `aggregate` also returns a dataframe, but the second column is of class `character`, `"(1, 2, ..., 100)"` and `"(101, 102, ..., 200)"`.

Comment: What is `dat` argument?

Comment: @Patris Sorry, I messed up! `dat` is the dataframe. Edited the code to add it.