# R: how can I transform dataframe to transaction

Tags: r

this is the dataset that I have

[image]

I'd like to transform the data to transaction using

```
trans<- as(data, "transactions")
```

and all data columns go into one column

I tried this below codes and doesn't work

```
trans<- as(data$Finding.Labels, "transactions")
```

I wnat to transform it like this way.

[image]

**How can I do?**

*Thanks!!!*

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313450/how-to-convert-data-frame-to-transactions-for-arules