# How to structure data for arules

Tags: r, dataframe, arules, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to understand how to use arules to do some association for work. I've got some dummy data and I've written this in R Studio as follows:

```
sales_list <- split(sales$ProductName, paste(sales$SalesOrderID))
```

My table sales contains 2 pieces of data - product name and the salesorder

However, when I've tried to split it out into a dataframe its turning into one big list. It just appears to be a list and I cant attempt to do any association rules on this.

[image]

Comment: A more common use of the `split` function would be e.g. `sales_list <- split(sales, sales$SalesOrderID)`. But I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I’m trying to do some basic association rules to find frequent item sets. I’m really new to r so I’ve been stumbling around trying to get the data into a format to play with and I keep drawing a blank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert data.frame to transactions for arules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313450/how-to-convert-data-frame-to-transactions-for-arules)